# make the average with 2 values from Json with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I got one problem because I don't know exactly how to do this.

I have one JSON and I want to make the average using two values from JSON

JSON

```
[
        {
            "player": {
              "info": {
                "position": "D",
                "shirtNum": 4,
                "positionInfo": "Centre/Right Central Defender"
              },
              "nationalTeam": {
                "isoCode": "BE",
                "country": "Belgium",
                "demonym": "Belgian"
              },
              "age": "27 years 139 days",
              "name": {
                "first": "Toby",
                "last": "Alderweireld"
              },
              "id": 4916,
              "currentTeam": {
                "name": "Tottenham Hotspur",
                "teamType": "FIRST",
                "shortName": "Spurs",
                "id": 21
              }
            },
            "stats": [
              {
                "name": "goals",
                "value": 5
              },
              {
                "name": "losses",
                "value": 20
              },
              {
                "name": "wins",
                "value": 48
              },
              {
                "name": "draws",
                "value": 23
              },
              {
                "name": "fwd_pass",
                "value": 1533
              },
              {
                "name": "goal_assist",
                "value": 2
              },
              {
                "name": "appearances",
                "value": 80
              },
              {
                "name": "mins_played",
                "value": 6953
              },
              {
                "name": "backward_pass",
                "value": 308
              }
            ]
          }]
```

I made one function in AngularJS but I don't know if is good or I'm calling in the HTML good to show the average between the value of goals and the mins_played.

The function in Angular what I did is this

```
$scope.mediaGoals = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.Jugador.stats.length; i++) {
            for (var x=0; x< $scope.Jugador.stats[i].stats.length; x++) {
              switch($scope.Jugador.stats[i].stats[x].name) {
                case 'goals':
                 var tmp_goals = $scope.Jugador.stats[i].stats[x].value;
                break;
                case 'mins_played':
                 var tmp_mins = $scope.Jugador.stats[i].stats[x].value;
                break;

              }
            }
            $scope.Jugador.stats[i].media = tmp_goals/tmp_mins;
        }
    }
```

And I made this HTML

```
<div class="stadistics">
     <div class="cont-desc-player" ng-repeat="stat in Jugador.stats">
          <div class="desc-player separador" ng-if="stat.name == 'appearances'">
               <span class="txt-estadistics">Appearances</span>
               <span class="num-estadistics">{{stat.value}}</span>
           </div>
           <div class="desc-player separador" ng-if="stat.name == 'goals'">
                <span class="txt-estadistics">Goals</span>
                <span class="num-estadistics">{{stat.value}}</span>
           </div>
           <div class="desc-player separador" ng-if="stat.name == 'goal_assist'">
                <span class="txt-estadistics">Assists</span>
                <span class="num-estadistics">{{stat.value}}</span>
           </div>
           <div class="desc-player separador" ng-if="stat.mediaGoals()">
                <span class="txt-estadistics">Goals per match</span>
                <span class="num-estadistics">{{stat.media}}</span>
           </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Please, can you help me with it?, because I don't know if I made the function good and it doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a few issues that I will try to make it clear for you. Let's start with the HTML.

`ng-if="stat.mediaGoals()"` will ever be matched, because the object `stat` does not have a `mediaGoals` function, and even if it has it, your `mediaGoals` function returns nothing, `undefined` to be more specific. Also, `mediaGoals` in this case, is a real performance killer.

My recommendation is to parse/convert the `JSON` in the service that loads it, converting the content into something more easy to handle in the HTML.

As I don't know the code that loads the `JSON`, I will adapt an illustrative example of your code and hope it helps.

Suppose we are using `$http` to load the `JSON` from an `API`

```
$http(requestConfig)
    .then(function(response){
        var players = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            var item = response.data[i];
            var player = {
                player: item.player,
                stats: { media: 0 }
            };
            var tmp_goals = 0;
            var tmp_mins = 0;

            for (var x=0; x < item.stats.length; x++) {
                var stat = item.stats[x];

                player.stats[stat.name] = stat.value;

                switch(stat.name) {
                    case 'goals':
                        tmp_goals = stat.value;
                    break;
                    case 'mins_played':
                        tmp_mins = stat.value;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (tmp_mins > 0) {
                player.stats.media = tmp_goals/tmp_mins;
            }

            players.push(player);
        }

        return players;
    });
```

Now, every time we get a single item from this list, it will look like this:

```
{
    player: {
      info: ...same from anwser
    },
    stats: {
        appearances: 80,
        backward_pass: 308,
        draws: 23,
        fwd_pass: 1533,
        goal_assist: 2,
        goals: 5,
        losses: 20,
        media: 0.0007191140514885661,
        mins_played: 6953,
        wins: 48
    }
}
```

Note that I did not include some info for brevity. But now, when we set the value to `$scope.Jugador` with one item from the parsed/converted list, the HTML will become much simpler, not need of `ngRepeat` or `ngIf`.

```
<div class="stadistics">
    <div class="cont-desc-player">
        <div class="desc-player separador">
           <span class="txt-estadistics">Appearances</span>
           <span class="num-estadistics">{{Jugador.stats.appearances}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="desc-player separador">
            <span class="txt-estadistics">Goals</span>
            <span class="num-estadistics">{{Jugador.stats.goals}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="desc-player separador">
            <span class="txt-estadistics">Assists</span>
            <span class="num-estadistics">{{Jugador.stats.goal_assist}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="desc-player separador">
            <span class="txt-estadistics">Goals per match</span>
            <span class="num-estadistics">{{Jugador.stats.media}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or probably you want to keep the `ngIf` and only show the info if the value is greater than 0

```
<div class="desc-player separador" data-ng-if="Jugador.stats.media > 0">
    <span class="txt-estadistics">Goals per match</span>
    <span class="num-estadistics">{{Jugador.stats.media}}</span>
</div>
```

It is all up to you from now on, hope it help.

**EDIT:**
If you want to continue with your approach on `mediaGoals` function, then you need to invoke it in your controller before you set the value to `Jugador`, so, it needs some changes.

```
$scope.Jugador = mediaGoals($scope.players[0]);


function mediaGoals(jugador) {
    var tmp_goals = 0;
    var tmp_mins = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < jugador.stats.length; i++) {
        switch(jugador.stats[i].name) {
            case 'goals':
              tmp_goals = jugador.stats[i].value;
            break;
            case 'mins_played':
              tmp_mins = jugador.stats[i].value;
            break;
        }

    }

    jugador.stats.push({ name: 'media', value: tmp_mins > 0 ? tmp_goals/tmp_mins : 0 });

    return jugador;
}
```

Adjust `$scope.players[0]` to your needs.

Now, your HTML can change to this

```
<div class="desc-player separador" ng-if="stat.name == 'media'">
    <span class="txt-estadistics">Goals per match</span>
    <span class="num-estadistics">{{stat.value}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: At this moment my HTML show Appearances, Goals and Assists but not Goals per match. I wrote here $scope.players =[...] because my JSON is inside the controller and in the HTML I put ng-repeat="stat in Jugador.stats" to show all the detais about stat and then the ng-if to show only the value what I want inside the div and actualy I'm trying to make the average af goals per match, for this I created that function, maybe I did it bad, and I tryed to call it from the HTML

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing bad, but if I do this, all the other things what I did don't work, because before I show couple of details of the player, depending whitch player you have selected in one select, you can see the details about this player. I create the `ng-if` because I have to show couple of stats not all and then create the average for goals per match and passes per minuteand I asked only for one because haveing one I got the other